# Reverse geocoding multiple Lat\Long points in single go with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, reverse-geocoding

I have a file which is having Lat\Longs for thousand of records, I need address for all these records to make it useful, I got a way to reverse geocode these records one by one but this process is time taking.

Can anyone suggest, how to reverse geocode multiple records in QGIS?

Comment: Thanks, MappaGnosis. That site is currently down but I dug around and found this one https://www.doogal.co.uk/BatchReverseGeocoding.php

Answer (score 3):

While bulk geocoding can be done through MMQGIS and reverse geocoding of individual points can be done through the geocode plugin, I don't know of a plugin that will do bulk reverse geocoding.  However, there are many websites that allow you to do it for free.  One such is [here](http://www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com/batch-reverse-geocode/#.WKrINX9WLZU) which I have used and [this site](https://geoservices.tamu.edu/Services/ReverseGeocoding/) provides some other links.